# Confused on how to implement the end function for doubly linked list

Tags: c++, iterator, doubly-linked-list

```
template <typename T>
class LinkedList {
  struct node;
  class Iterator;

 public:
  LinkedList() {}
  LinkedList(std::initializer_list<T> init_list) {
    this->operator=(init_list);
  }
  template <typename InputIterator>
  LinkedList(InputIterator first, InputIterator last) {
    for (; first != last; ++first)
      this->push_back(*first);
  }
  LinkedList(const LinkedList& another) {
    this->operator=(another);
  }
  ~LinkedList() {
    while (this->head) {
      node* old_head = this->head;
      this->head = old_head->next;
      delete old_head;
    }
  }
  Iterator begin() {
    return Iterator(this->head);
  }
  Iterator end() {
    return Iterator(this->tail->next);
  }
```

I tried to add an empty node at the tail->next, however I can't get the result that I want. And without the empty node I just get a segmentation fault when I run the code.

```
  class Iterator {
   friend class LinkedList;
   public:
    using iterator_category = std::bidirectional_iterator_tag;
    using value_type = T;
    using difference_type = int;
    using pointer = T*;
    using reference = T&;
    Iterator(node* ptr) : ptr(ptr) {}
    Iterator(const Iterator& other) {
      this->operator=(other);
    }

    Iterator& operator=(const Iterator& that) {
      this->ptr = that.ptr;
      return *this;
    }
    Iterator& operator++() {
      this->ptr = ptr->next;
      return *this;
    }
    Iterator operator++(int) {
      Iterator tmp(*this);
      this->operator++();
      return tmp;
    }
    Iterator& operator--() {
      this->ptr = ptr->prev;
      return *this;
    }
    Iterator operator--(int) {
      Iterator tmp(*this);
      this->operator--();
      return tmp;
    }
    bool operator!=(Iterator that) const { return !(this->operator==(that)); }
    bool operator==(Iterator that) const { return this->ptr == that.ptr; }
    T& operator*() const { return ptr->data; }
    Iterator* operator->() { return this; }
  private:
    node* ptr = nullptr;
  };
```

Here is the main function I used to test and when I print the stl_list end() it prints the size of the list. I'm confused what should be returned for this function. I thought it was supposed to be an empty nullptr that points to the location after the tail.

```
int main() {
  std::list<int> stl_list{1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
  cs19::LinkedList<int> our_list{1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
  std::cout << *stl_list.begin() << '\n';
  std::cout << *our_list.begin() << '\n';
  std::cout << *our_list.end() << '\n';
  std::cout << *stl_list.end() << '\n';
}
```

Comment: `*stl_list.end()` makes it have undefined behavior. You are not allowed to "dereference" `end()` iterators.

Comment: Suggestion: Make `iterator` a nested class of your `LinkedList`. It makes things a little easier. Also, please provide a [mre].

Comment: Since dereferencing end blew up, `operator--` is not going to work on the end iterator. You'll have to dereference it to get `prev`.

Comment: `this->operator=(init_list);` -- `LinkedList(const LinkedList& another) { this->operator=(another); }` -- Off topic, but I suggest not doing this at all.  Write a standalone `copy constructor` without the help of `operator=` and then implement `operator=` in terms of the copy constructor by utilizing copy/swap.  Also, if you're going to call `operator=` from the copy constructor, somewhere in the `operator=` (which you didn't post), you will have to `delete[]` the old data.  But there is no indication you've initialized the data to `nullptr`, so that the `delete[]` will work correctly.

Answer (score 2):

> Confused on how to implement the end function for doubly linked list

You could create a special node type that is *one past the end* node which only has a `prev` pointer.

```cpp
template <typename T>
class LinkedList {
    struct empty_node { // used for end iterator
        empty_node* prev = nullptr;
    };

    struct node : empty_node {
        empty_node* next;
        T data;
    };
```

Your `LinkedList` would then have an instance of `empty_node` whos only purpose is to let `prev` point back to the last real node. You'd then instantiate the `end()` iterator with a pointer to this `empty_node`.

You'd then use `empty_node*` everywhere until stepping the iterator forward or dereferencing an iterator.

Example with comments to explain:

```cpp
template <typename T>
class LinkedList {
    // node definitions as above

public:
    class Iterator {
    public:
        using iterator_category = std::bidirectional_iterator_tag;
        using value_type = T;
        using difference_type = int;
        using pointer = T*;
        using reference = T&;

        Iterator(empty_node* ptr) : ptr(ptr) {}
        Iterator(const Iterator& other) : ptr(other.ptr) {}

        Iterator& operator=(const Iterator& that) {
            ptr = that.ptr;
            return *this;
        }
        Iterator& operator++() {
            // If the user steps forward, the iterator can't be at the end
            // or the program will have undefined behavior as per the usual
            // contract, so a cast is fine:
            ptr = static_cast<node*>(ptr)->next;
            return *this;
        }
        Iterator operator++(int) {
            Iterator tmp(*this);
            ++*this;
            return tmp;
        }
        Iterator& operator--() {
            ptr = ptr->prev;
            return *this;
        }
        Iterator operator--(int) {
            Iterator tmp(*this);
            --*this;
            return tmp;
        }

        bool operator==(Iterator that) const { return this->ptr == that.ptr; }
        
        bool operator!=(Iterator that) const {
            return !(*this == that);
        }

        // Dereferencing is not allowed if the iterator is at the end so
        // cast is fine:
        reference operator*() const { return static_cast<node*>(ptr)->data; }
        pointer operator->() { return &static_cast<node*>(ptr)->data; }

    private:
        empty_node* ptr = nullptr;
    };

    LinkedList() = default;

    template <typename InputIterator>
    LinkedList(InputIterator first, InputIterator last) {
        for (; first != last; ++first) this->push_back(*first);
    }

    // Delegate to ctor taking iterators:
    LinkedList(std::initializer_list<T> init_list)
        : LinkedList(init_list.begin(), init_list.end()) {}

    // Copy ctor - delegate to ctor taking iterators too:
    LinkedList(const LinkedList& another)
        : LinkedList(another.begin(), another.end()) {}

    ~LinkedList() {
        // As long as it's not pointing at end, cast is fine:
        for(empty_node* next; head != &beyond_end; head = next) {
            next = static_cast<node*>(head)->next;
            delete static_cast<node*>(head);
        }
    }

    void push_back(const T& value) {
        // Create a new node where `prev` points at the current last real node
        // and `next` points at our empty end node:
        node* nn = new node{{beyond_end.prev}, &beyond_end, value};

        // link it: 
        if (head != &beyond_end) { // not the first node added
            // the previous node must be a real node, so cast is fine:
            static_cast<node*>(beyond_end.prev)->next = nn;
        } else {                   // the first node added
            head = nn;
        }
        beyond_end.prev = nn; // link beyond_end to the last real node
    }

    Iterator begin() { return Iterator(head); }
    Iterator end() { return Iterator(&beyond_end); } // use `beyond_end` for end()

private:
    empty_node* head = &beyond_end;   // start pointing at the empty node
    empty_node beyond_end;            // note, not a pointer
};
```

So, instead of a `node* tail;` you'll have an instance of an `empty_node` in your `LinkedList`. It will have the same size as a `node*` so it doesn't waste space.

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/oba77cKKM)

You could also store both the head and tail pointer in an `empty_node` to remove all casts except when dereferencing/`delete`ing.

```
template <typename T>
class LinkedList {
    struct empty_node { // used for end iterator
        empty_node* prev = nullptr;
        empty_node* next = nullptr;
    };

    struct node : empty_node {
        T data;
    }
```

It requires minor changes to the example:
[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/sc4nM7heq)

Comment: It does seem like a lot of casting to save the space of a `node *` and a `T`

Comment: @Caleth Yeah, I made an alternative that only requires casts when dereferencing. I still want to avoid the space of an extra `T`.